# Cannot access admin console for a google cloud endpoints project running on xxx.appspot.com

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a google cloud endpoint deployed and running on myapi.appspot.com. However, I cannot seem to access the admin console at the URL :

```
https://myapi.appspot.com/_ah/admin
```

in the same way as I can when running on localhost at

```
http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to go to :

Datastore Viewer under

https://appengine.google.com/

in order to see the data since there seems to be no way to view the data from https://cloud.google.com

It is also accessible under Storage -> Cloud Datastore -> Query as I later found out.